# Is it rigorous to prove that for a subgraph $G$ from $H$, $\alpha (G) \leq \alpha (H)$ by proving that $\omega (\bar G) < \omega (\bar H)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

I want to prove the following:

Let $G$ be a subgraph of $H$. $\alpha (G) \leq \alpha (H)$

This is my proof, but I'm not sure that it is rigorous:

Suppose that $G$ is a subgraph of $H$, and that $\alpha (G) > \alpha (H)$. Then, $\omega (\bar G) > \omega (\bar H)$. Then, if $H$ contains some clique of size $k$, $G$ contains some clique larger than $k$. Then, $G$ + ($H$ - $G$) has a larger clique than $H$, which is a contradiction as $G$ + ($H$ - $G$) = $H$. Thus, $\alpha (G) \leq \alpha (H)$.

Is this rigorous? Is there a better way to prove it without looking to the complement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the independent set? This is not true if $G$ is not an **induced** subgraph. For example, $H$ can be the complete graph and $G$ is the empty graph.

Comment: I'm using $\alpha$ to refer to the independence number of $G$.

Comment: Although - I guess that the counter example still holds. I think this means the claim is false?

Comment: Yes, it is only true when the subgraph is an induced subgraph. In this case, the proof is because if $G$ is an induced subgraph of $H$, then an independent set in $G$ will remain an independent set in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is not rigorous because the claim is not true. If $H$ is complete and $G$ has no edges, then $\alpha (G) > \alpha (H)$.